# Bind reference in puppetlabs-dhcp

Tags: bind, puppet, dhcp

In the examples for `puppetlabs-dhcp` it shows the module interfacing with BIND to do allow dynamic DNS entries.

```
class { 'dhcp':
  service_ensure => running,
  dnsdomain      => [
    'dc1.example.net',
    '1.0.10.in-addr.arpa',
  ],
  nameservers  => ['10.0.1.20'],
  ntpservers   => ['us.pool.ntp.org'],
  interfaces   => ['eth0'],
  dnsupdatekey => '/etc/bind/keys.d/rndc.key',
  dnskeyname   => 'rndc-key',
  require      => Bind::Key['rndc-key'],
  pxeserver    => '10.0.1.50',
  pxefilename  => 'pxelinux.0',
  omapi_port   => 7911,
}
```

https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-dhcp#usage

The example appears to reference a specific `Bind` Puppet module, but as there is no official module and a number of competing BIND Puppet modules in Forge, is there a specific version it's intended to work with?

Comment: To find the dependencies of a module, you can check its `metadata.json`. That would be here: https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-dhcp/blob/master/metadata.json. It has both concat and stdlib listed, neither of which contain any reference to bind. That means time to file an issue on the github tracker.

Comment: Oh also, this module is using puppetlabs_spec_helper, so you could also check the dependencies in the `fixtures.yml`.